# Environmental impact of ferries

Tags: trains, ferries, aircraft, ethical-travel, environment

When I travel, I try to limit my environmental impact. I don't want to refrain from travelling completely, but when I do travel, I tend to favour ground-level transportation over air-transportation, if distances are not too large (e.g., if traveling over-land would take more than three days, I might fly anyway.

A well-filled train usually has a much lower ecological footprint per traveller-kilometer than an æroplane, particularly if the train is hydro-electrical, such as in Sweden. High speed trains and diesel trains are already worse, but still considerably better than flying. But what about ferries? Fuel used by (fast) ferries can be quite dirty. On the other hand, ferries may carry over a thousand travellers, sometimes several thousands.

How does the ecological footprint per traveller of a typical, well-filled ferry compare to the ecological footprint per traveller of an æroplane?  For the sake of this question, I'm interested in ferries going out on the open ocean on routes that potentially compete with airplanes, not in local ferries crossing a river, a lake, a fjord, or a small sound (there's probably no mode of transportation spanning as many orders of magnitude in size as a boat).

For example, travelling from Stockholm to Warsaw, one might identify four alternatives with a somewhat similar travel class, where all day trains are 2nd class and all overnight accommodation (train or ferry) is with a bed/berth in a shared cabin.

- flying in an ordinary economy seat
- by train+ferry via Nynäshamn–Gdańsk
- by train (almost) all the way via Copenhagen, Hamburg, Berlin (a considerable detour)
- (only part of the year) by train-on-ferry via Malmö and Berlin ([Berlin Night Express](http://www.berlin-night-express.com/))

Which one is the most ecological?

Comment: Personally I would like to have the comparable data of any available classes, so I can make a choice and see the difference between them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Emissions figures for ferries are surprisingly hard to find compared to those for cars, trains, and aircraft. The best source I've found for ferries is this report:

Åkerman, Jonas (2008). *Klimatpåverkan från utrikes resor* ["Climate effects from foreign travel"]. Report TRITA-INFRA-FMS 2008:7. Stockholm: Royal Institute of Technology.

Åkerman looks at foreign travel by residents of Sweden. He sources ferry emissions figures from public environmental impact reports and personal communications from Silja Line and Viking Line, the main operators of ferries between Sweden and Finland. These are the final figures he arrives at for ferries and other major modes of transport:

| Mode of transport | Average greenhouse emissions (kg CO₂-equiv. / passenger-km) |
| --- | --- |
| Air | 0.24 |
| Car | 0.09 |
| Ferry | 0.17 |
| Bus | 0.02 |
| Rail | 0.04 |

There are caveats and significant uncertainties attached to all these figures, but even taking them as order-of-magnitude estimates indicates that the train produces far fewer greenhouse emissions than the ferry.

Estimating the relevant distances for your Stockholm-Warsaw trip with Google Maps gives me:

| Route | Distance (km) | Emissions (kg CO₂-equiv. / passenger) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Air, direct | 800 | 192 |
| Ferry + Rail via Gdańsk | 570 + 350 | 97 + 14 = 111 |
| Rail via Hamburg | 1800 | 72 |

I didn't do the maths for "Berlin Night Express" route, but I imagine it would be similar to the train-only route since the Trelleborg-Sassnitz crossing is a short one.

Comment: Interesting!  As a side note, I'm surprised by the bus vs. rail figure, considering that rail is often electric and electric rail may be nuclear or renewable, whereas buses are essentially always diesel.

Comment: It would also be interesting to see how the emissions of ferries are divided between foot passengers, car passengers, and freight sharing a ferry

Comment: @gerrit Yes, that surprised me too. My guess is that it's skewed by the restriction to *international* travel, which in the case of buses often means pre-booked charter coaches with high occupancy ratios. Åkerman assumes 70% occupancy for buses which is probably reasonable in this case, but would probably be unrealistically high for a lot of local/regional bus services.

Comment: I suspect part of the issue is that most ferries are car ferries, so the ferry has to lug around not only the passengers but also their cars.

Answer (score 11):

Comparing aeroplanes and trains shows that aeroplanes are very much the least ecologically friendly mode of transport. As an example from http://www.seat61.com/CO2flights.htm:

[image]

A [site](http://driving.drive-alive.co.uk/relative_carbon_emissions.htm) which has some limited data comparing plane, train and car+ferry gives us the following data, but I would assume that the car emissions skew the numbers somewhat, which leads me to believe that the ferry could be the lowest impact:

[image]

Caveat: these only take CO2 into account, and there are many other ways transport impacts the environment.

Answer (score 4):

It's worth pointing out that most figures for ferries assume you are taking a car.

Most of the answers already given use such figures. However, there is also the important case to consider of foot passengers. [According to Seat61](https://www.seat61.com/CO2flights.htm), the UK's DEFRA uses a nominal figure of 22.54 grams of CO2 per foot passenger kilometre, which would put ferries within the same order of magnitude as trains and buses.

Comment: If anyone can find a primary source for this DEFRA figure I'd much appreciate it, I had a quick Google and couldn't spot one

Comment: Huh, this is interesting!  The same order as trains, despite trains being largely electric and ferries using some quite dirty fuel?  Passengers also have a lot more space per person on ferries, and water has quite high resistance.  I agree that a primary source would be very nice to have here.

Comment: I suspect the main factor there is that trains go much, much faster than ferries. I could be wrong though!

Comment: I've been on ferries that were [faster than 60 km/h](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/10044/2509), but I agree that usually trains are faster :)  (and the footprint of 100 km/h speedboats might be very much worse than the DEFRA nominal figure)

Comment: The issue with caclulating the impact of going on a ferry is that you need to take in to account the energy cost of moving and powering the passenger accommodation. I think that the DEFRA figures vastly underestimate the emissions. Look at cruise ships for example.

Comment: There may be some pointers at https://www.gov.uk/government/statistical-data-sets/energy-and-environment-data-tables-env

Comment: @KristvanBesien most passenger ferries are not particularly similar to cruise ships...

Comment: @Muzer Depends.  Some modern RORO-ferries like the [MS Color Fantasy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MS_Color_Fantasy) get quite close to cruise ships IMO, whereas others like [MS Wawel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MS_Wawel) are much more basic.  Small [cable ferries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cable_ferry) might even be human powered (but are not the scope of the question).

Comment: The keyword here is [*cruiseferry*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cruiseferry).

Comment: @gerrit  but where does the electricity come from (and when does the data on electricity generation come from)?  For that matter how is the weighting between diesel and electric trains calculated?  That will be very country- and distance- dependent

Comment: @ChrisH-UK True, of course.  At least in Germany, France, and Sweden, long distance trains are run on electricity that has little or no carbon footprint.  But the question here was about ferries, not trains.

Comment: @gerrit it was, though the ferry options include trains for a long distance that makes it significant. Sadly here in the UK there are a lot of long-distance diesel trains.  Even the line I use is only partially electrified so all the trains still have to carry generators.  But even in countries with a decent mix of renewables/nuclear, the marginal generation is still largely fossil fuel, so if the trains stopped it would be coal or gas that stopped burning - better of course is to take the average carbon intensity of the electricity system.  Far better than diesel trains.

Comment: @gerrit, ships, even ships burning the dirtiest bunker oil available, are phenomenally efficient -- a cargo ship is nearly an order of magnitude more efficient than a train for moving goods.  The thing that hampers ferries is the low load factor: even a fully-loaded ferry is sparsely loaded compared to a passenger train.

Comment: @gerrit what on earth do you mean "little to no carbon footprint". That is obvious nonsense.

Comment: @Turkeyphant In Germanyand Sweden  long-distance trains run on 100% renewable electricity, and in France they run mostly on nuclear power.  Both sources of electricity have little to no carbon footprint.  Yes, there is still a carbon footprint in producing the trains and the infrastructure, but the overall carbin footprint is minimal compared to internal combustion engine cars or airplanes.

Comment: @Muzer: The ferries across the Baltic are pretty much like cruise ships. They are even marketed as "mini cruises". There are restaurants, movie theatres, discos, a swimming pool etc... All these amenities need to be moved too. Which is why just assuming that a foot passenger + luggage weighs 100kg vastly underestimates the carbon footprint. For that kind of trips flying really is the best option.

Comment: @gerrit renewable energy isn't close to having no carbon footprint.

Comment: @Turkeyphant Renewable energy, by definition, has little to no carbon footprint.

Comment: @gerrit that is utter nonsense as you well know, what on earth gives you that idea?

Answer (score 1):

[Ecopassenger](https://ecopassenger.hafas.de/bin/query.exe/en?L=vs_uic&) provides a search engine comparing the environmental impact of various travel options.  They're focussed on trains, planes, and automobiles, but some train routes include ferries.  Comparing only trains shows, as expected, that trains are by far the most environmentally friendly in all aspects:

[image: Hamburg - München]
*Searching for Hamburg – München*

One ferry included in train search engines is Stockholm - Turku.  Searching for Stockholm - Helsinki includes this ferry, and shows very bad news for ferries (at least this particular ferry):

[image: Stockholm - Helsinki]
*Searching for Stockholm - Helsinki*

This seems confusing, because the [methodology](https://ecopassenger.hafas.de/hafas-res/download/Ecopassenger_Methodology_Data.pdf) states about ferries:

> For several relations ferries are part of the journey. In this version of EcoPassenger it was not possible to estimate the energy consumption and emissions for ferries because the timetable data of Merits (see the following section) did not allow identifying ferries as separate transport mode. Thus the distance for the ferry transport with train and car is considered, but no separate energy and emission values.

which makes me wonder what the big orange bar is about.  I have asked the UIC (which hosts Ecopassenger) if this result really means what it seems, because it would seem to indicate flying is much cleaner than train+ferry, which is very different from what I thought or from other estimates.

Answer (score 1):

In the EU, there is the THETIS law, mandating publicisation of CO2 emission by ferries.

However, this data is not very useful in itself and a lot of factors have to be taken into account for a fair per passenger calc ([Writeup (in French)](https://hackmd.io/@laem/empreinte-ferry), [study](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/342589035_EU-MRV_an_analysis_of_2018%27s_Ro-Pax_CO2_data))

From the site made from the above writeup [futur.eco](https://futur.eco/simulateur/transport/ferry/empreinte-du-voyage), a comparaison between plane and ferry would be as such for a leg between Marseille and Bastia in Corsica

| Mode | Distance (km) | Emissions per passenger (kg) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Plane | 361 | 43 |
| Ferry | 338 | 124 |

The ferry calculation is as follow :

- Travel duration : 18:45 - 08:00 (N+1)
- Cabin : yes
- Consumption of services : no
- Car : no
- Nb. of passengers : 1

The Plane calculation is from [IATA CO2 Connect](https://www.iata.org/en/services/statistics/intelligence/co2-connect/iata-co2-connect-passenger-calculator/) from MRS-BIA in economy using the A320ceo as this is the most used plane on that route

I haven't had the time to make other comparaisons but if the data from THETIS and the parsing from futur.eco is to be believed, taking the ferry has an extremely larger footprint than flying