# World's fastest ferry route

Tags: factoids, ferries, where-on-earth

Last summer, I was impressed by the speed of the Norwegian *hurtigbåt* M/S Fjordprinsessa, operating near Tromsø, travelling so fast that travellers are not allowed on-deck and are recommended to remain seated and fasten their seatbelts. I don't recall the actual speed, but another of their boats does [Tromsø – Harstad in 2h40m](http://tromskortet.no/LinkClick.aspx?fileticket=A9moZbvjpNc%3d&tabid=642&language=nb-NO), a distance of around 160 km, meaning an average speed of 60 km/hour including one stop. Googling told me that the [Fjord Cat](http://no.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C2%ABFjord_Cat%C2%BB) on Kristiansand–Hirtshals does 45 *knots* or 83 km/hour, while the [Shinas](http://gulfnews.com/news/gulf/oman/oman-launches-high-speed-ferry-1.120359) in Oman does 51 knots (94 km/hour), but I think those are maximum speeds and not average speeds. The Oman article claims "the world's fastest diesel-powered passenger ferry", but "fastest" can have several definitions, which leads me to my question:

**What is the world's fastest point-to-point scheduled ferry route?** By *fastest* in this context, I mean the distance divided by the time according to the timetable, similar to [this Wikipedia table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Land_speed_record_for_rail_vehicles#World_fastest_point-to-point_average_speeds_in_commercial_operations) for trains.

Comment: There's several places around the world with hydrofoil ferries. There's a pair between Fukuoka Japan and Busan Korea. And a couple were used for the Batumi Georgia ↔ Sochi Russia route though I think they're not running right now due to Russia. I'm hunting for speed info ...

Comment: [Passenger Hydrofoil list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrofoil#Current_operation) might be helpful here. Apparently there aren't that many types of these in operation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Oman, between Muscat and the exclave Musandam, operate the Shinas and the Hormuz.

As reported by [The Week](https://web.archive.org/web/20080803020355/http://www.theweek.co.om/disCon.aspx?Cval=934), the Shinas has a top speed of 96 km/hour, whereas the Hormuz has a top speed of *104 km/hour*:

> It’s not a speedboat and it’s definitely not an F1 superboat. Call it the bullet ferry or a super catamaran if you will, but whichever way you look at it, the Shinas is probably as fast as it gets on water in a passenger ferry anywhere in the world.

Answer (score 6):

[Hovertravel](http://www.hovertravel.co.uk/) operates hovercraft from Southsea, Portsmouth to Ryde, Isle of Wight. One of the types of hovercraft they are using is [BHC AP1-88](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AP1-88), which has 50 knots (93km/h) top speed.

Answer (score 4):

I remember that back in the day, some high speed boats were used to go from France to Corsica. I could find [some archives about these boats](http://xav99.chez.com/ngvsncm.htm){french} (now they are too expensive to run because of oil prices).

So it says that Nice-Calvi took 2h45 at a speed of 37 knots (70 km/h). Using Google Maps, the distance of current route is 208 km (which would mean the speed is 75km/h). So I suppose it means that the route is probably now longer but yeah, the average speed was at least 70km/h at that time.

Answer (score 3):

The high-speed ferry operated by Buquebus travels between Buenos Aires, Argentina and Montevideo, Uruguay. It achieves a high speed of 58 knots (107 km/h) and a travel speed of 51 knots (95 km/h).
https://www.ship-technology.com/projects/francisco-high-speed-ferry/

Comment: Around the world of ferries, this one is still known to be the fastest, however, I doubt it goes full speed often.

Answer (score 2):

Most answers here cite top speed, which isn't really what the OP has asked. So rewriting this we get

1. The HSC Franciso between Montevideo and Buenos Aires has a scheduled trip time of 2h 15m and the distance is 203 km, which makes for an average speed of 90.2 km/h.

I coudn't find a time table for the Hormus, assuming that either it's not running anymore or is suspended due to Covid.

Answer (score 1):

The Ekranoplan is probably the fastest ferry, managing well over 400 knots.  http://www.travelcentre.com.au/travel/airshows/Russian/russia_ekranoplan.htm

I am not sure whether they have them as scheduled ferry trips any more or whether they are charter trips, but what a stupendous craft!

Comment: The one you mention was military craft (now defunct). Regarding ferries: *"Other larger designs as ferries and heavy transports have been proposed, but have not been carried to fruition."* (see: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ground_effect_vehicle#GEVs_since_the_1980s))

Comment: The smaller designs are the ones I was thinking of, although I would love to see the Caspian Sea Monster at full speed!

Answer (score 0):

The HSC *Fransico* (a catamaran ferry) has a top speed of 58 knots (107 kmh), however I don't know if she does that in regular service. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incat#Products